# R : cannot run partial least square regression on more than one descriptor

Tags: r, csv, regression, descriptor

I generated a csv table "T.CSV" :

```
"system","response","NIR.a","NIR.b"
 1,1,2,3
 2,4,5,6
 3,7,8,9
```

for which plsr succeeds for one descriptor but fails for multiple descriptors :

```
> library(pls)
> j <- read.csv(file="T.CSV",header=T,sep=",")
> head(j)
system response NIR.a NIR.b
1      1        1     2     3
2      2        4     5     6
3      3        7     8     9
> mod <- plsr(response ~ NIR.a , data = j ,  ncomp=1 )
> mod <- plsr(response ~ NIR , data = j ,  ncomp=1 )
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'NIR' not found
```

However, if I load the "oliveoil" example of the pls package, regression works with more than one descriptor :

```
> data(oliveoil)
> head(oliveoil)
chemical.Acidity chemical.Peroxide chemical.K232 chemical.K270 chemical.DK
G1             0.73              12.7         1.9           0.139       0.003
G2             0.19              12.3         1.678         0.116      -0.004
G3             0.26              10.3         1.629         0.116      -0.005
G4             0.67              13.7         1.701         0.168      -0.002
G5             0.52              11.2         1.539         0.119      -0.001
I1             0.26              18.7         2.117         0.142       0.001
sensory.yellow sensory.green sensory.brown sensory.glossy sensory.transp
G1           21.4          73.4          10.1           79.7           75.2
G2           23.4          66.3           9.8           77.8           68.7
G3           32.7          53.5           8.7           82.3           83.2
G4           30.2          58.3          12.2           81.1           77.1
G5           51.8          32.5             8           72.4           65.3
I1           40.7          42.9          20.1           67.7           63.5
sensory.syrup
G1          50.3
G2          51.7
G3          45.4
G4          47.8
G5          46.5
I1          52.2
```

Here pls works for multiple descriptors :

```
> mod <- plsr(chemical ~ sensory , data = oliveoil ,  ncomp=1 )
>
```

Can you please advise on where I've been wrong in my 1st table ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: There is no column named `NIR`.  If you look at the `str(oliveoil)`, there are only two columns.  The `sensory` is a matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the `str(oliveoil)`, the 'sensory' is a `matrix` with `n` columns.  So, to use the formula in that way, the "NIR" should be also a `matrix` inside a `data.frame`

```
j1 <- j[1:2]
j1["NIR"] <- as.matrix(setNames(j[3:4], letters[1:2]))
mod <- plsr(response ~ NIR , data = j1 ,  ncomp=1 )
str(mod)
#List of 19
# $ coefficients   : num [1:2, 1, 1] 0.5 0.5
# ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
# .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "a" "b"
# .. ..$ : chr "response"
# .. ..$ : chr "1 comps"
# ----
```

#### data

```
j <- structure(list(system = 1:3, response = c(1L, 4L, 7L),
 NIR.a = c(2L, 
 5L, 8L), NIR.b = c(3L, 6L, 9L)), .Names = c("system", "response", 
 "NIR.a", "NIR.b"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Many thanks for your kind help, I'll try to use your example and adapt it to my case starting from a csv file.

Comment: well I'd like to do so but I need to have 15 reputation points and now I'm only having 10.. I'll try to do that when I reach 15. Many thanks again,

Answer (score 0):

In your command, `mod <- plsr(response ~ NIR , data = j ,  ncomp=1 )`, on the RHS of the `~` make sure the name of explanatory variables match **exactly** to the column names in the data (in terms of spelling, and upper/lower case). In R's response to `head` I notice there is no column called `NIR`. But there is one called `NIR.a` and one called `NIR.b`. Have you checked if replacing `NIR` with `NIR.a` or `NIR.b` works?